# How to resolve path issue using file system in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have file `post` to server so i can read the content on client side it works for first call but when i upload file second time i got below error it looks like some absolute path issue. How can i resolve this problem ?

server.js

```
export function create(req, res) {
 data.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files.file[0].path,'utf8');
     res.json(fileContent   );
    });
}
```

error

```
fileUpload.controller.js:14
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files.file[0].path, 'utf8');
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
```

Comment: check your `files` type while uploading.

Comment: It looks like the file is not uploaded based on the error. check `files.length` to make sure at least one file is uploaded

Comment: You should handle the `err` parameter - that probably would give you more helpful information.

Comment: if i print error i got this `[Error: write after end]` Any idea ?